# Android Studio Kotlin autocomplete symbols

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I've just now started playing around with Kotlin a little, so please forgive me for the newbie question.
I've noticed that a bunch of new symbols has been added in the autocomplete selection next to the options available[image: see the screenshot] , does anybody know what the round 'v' and the square 'v' indicate?(the 'v' inside a circle and the 'v' inside a square, on the LHS of the choices in the list after the little green padlock)
Or where I can find a symbols legend?
thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the "round 'v'" and the "square 'v'"?

Comment: sorry, I meant to say, the 'v' inside a circle and the 'v' inside a square, on the LHS of the choices in the list after the little green padlock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using kotlin-android-extensions plugin. This plugin just adds syntactic sugar among other things. For example, if a class has simple methods like:

```
public void setText(String text) {
    mText = text;
}
```

then you can use this function in kotlin like:

```
item_2.mText = text;
```

Basically the getter and setter methods can be accessed like member properties. If you compile it, the above code becomes:

```
item_2.setText(text);
```

So, the v symbol means that property now can be accessed like above in kotlin. Square means that only getter exists for that property. And circle means both getter/setter exists